# Почему - самоеды?

Tags: этимология

Северные народы (ненцев и прочих) раньше называли общим словом "самоеды". Почему такое название?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самоеды - урало-алтайское племя, близкое к финнам, но отличающееся от них типом и языком. Имя их произошло не от "само-едения", т. е. людоедства, а, вероятно, от Самееднам - названия, которое дают своей стране лопари, жившие некогда восточнее, чем теперь.

Answer (score 2):

Суоми, саами - искажение, а дальше еще больше в русском - *само,*  с приставкой. Это народное творчество. Не от того, что себя кушают, а от того, что самообеспеченные, свое едят - лопают, потому и лопари, и мало торгуют. Не стоит искать черных кошек там, где их нет.